# cloud build does not recognize build directory argument

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager, cloudbuild.yaml

I am trying to build a Cloud Run job with a trigger from Cloud Build and secrets from Secret Manager. I managed to get the trigger that I use to build my Dockerfile to run, but the build itself fails with the following error:

```
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "build image"
Step #0 - "build image": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0 - "build image": "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
Step #0 - "build image": See 'docker build --help'.
Step #0 - "build image": 
Step #0 - "build image": Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
Step #0 - "build image": 
Step #0 - "build image": Build an image from a Dockerfile
Finished Step #0 - "build image"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

What I have already tried:

1. Verified that there is a build directory in the command;
2. Rearranged the order of build arguments just in case;
3. I also tried breakout syntax (with '|' as one of the arguments), but it did not work out - the image was not built at all.
4. UPDATED: I tried running the build without `--build-arg`s and it started actually building! Looks like a bug.
   Here is my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```yaml
steps:
  - id: "build image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      ['-c', 'docker build --build-arg CONTAINER_PRIVATE_KEY=$$PRIVATE_KEY --build-arg CONTAINER_PUBLIC_KEY=$$PUBLIC_KEY -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_JOB_NAME} .']
    secretEnv: [ 'PRIVATE_KEY', 'PUBLIC_KEY' ]
  - id: "push image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: [ "push", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_JOB_NAME}" ]

  - id: "deploy to cloud run"
    name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
            [
              'beta', 'run', '${_JOB_NAME}',
              '--image', 'gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_JOB_NAME}',
              '--region', '${_REGION}',
              '--set-env-vars', "BUCKET=${_BUCKET}",
              '--set-env-vars', "MNT_DIR=${_MNT_DIR}"
            ]
images:
    - "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_JOB_NAME}"
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: "projects/${_PROJECT_ID_NUMBER}/secrets/${_CONTAINER_PRIVATE_KEY_SECRET_NAME}/versions/latest"
      env: "PRIVATE_KEY"
    - versionName: "projects/${_PROJECT_ID_NUMBER}/secrets/${_CONTAINER_PUBLIC_KEY_SECRET_NAME}/versions/latest"
      env: "PUBLIC_KEY"
```

Comment: Can you try with double quote " instead of simple '?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere tried changing quotes both in `entrypoint` and in `args`, didn't help, sadly. Same error

Comment: Hmmm, I think I already got this error. Can you try to display your secret content? I'm pretty sure you have a line return at the end. How did you create the secret? with the gcloud CLI?

Comment: I will try and check that now, but I created my secrets from gcloud CLI

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have just echoed the contents of both secrets from secret manager (with `gcloud secrets access etc`) to my terminal and no, there seems to be no newline at the end of either one

Comment: Did you use a `-n` when you created your secret with command line, like that `echo -n "my super secret data" | gcloud secrets create ...`

Comment: I did, in fact, my command looked like
`echo -n "secret_content" | gcloud secrets create secret_name --data-file=-`

Comment: Hmmm, no secret format issue. So, try to find a parameter/substition value with a space. Does _JOB_NAME contain space before? Secrets contains space before value also?

Comment: As I found out after some poking around, I updated my question with point 4 - for some reason this problem seems to be caused by `build-arg`s - if I remove them, Cloud Build actually proceeds to build the image. The issue is that I actually need these build args here and the image will be rather useless without them

Comment: That's why my first guess was about the secret format (line return, or space before/in the value.)

Comment: I was away from keyboard for a while so I can only verify now - no, that was not the issue, but I figured the problem out, I will post the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after extensive testing and trying out various options I have managed to figure out what was causing the issue, below is the correct argument string (it goes in the args):

```bash
["-c", "docker build --build-arg 'CONTAINER_PRIVATE_KEY=$$PRIVATE_KEY' --build-arg 'CONTAINER_PUBLIC_KEY=$$PUBLIC_KEY' -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_JOB_NAME} ."]
```

The problem was lack of single quotes around `build-arg`s' values. Basically, in this context a `build-arg` value is a single string, not a key-value pair